# Error on Raspberry Pi says 'Read-only file system'?

Tags: linux, bash, github, raspberry-pi, raspbian

For reference, this is the project I'm talking about here https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror

bash command being referenced: `bash -c "$(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/master/installers/raspberry.sh)"`

When I try to run the bash command to download and install MagicMirror, I get the error…

`Note.js installation Done!
Cloning MagicMirror...
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'MagicMirror'.: Read-only file system`

I tried to run the bash command again, but I got an error telling me that dpkg was interrupted and asked me to run another command, so I ran

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

and re-ran the bash command a 3rd time, only to arrive at the error

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).`

Some additional information:
I’m running the command as pi user.

I’m running Raspbian with PIXEL because when I download NOOBS to a micro-sd, ‘Raspbian’ doesn’t show up as an option (even with ethernet connected). I was assured by some people on reddit that Raspbian with PIXEL was the same, just with a UI.

I’ve wiped and re-installed NOOBS at least 4 times on this micro-sd card, taking about an hour each time, and all I want is a working mirror :(

Do I need to go about a different way of installing this software? I’m unfamiliar with linux so any simplified version is appreciated :)

Comment: This might be better on https://superuser.com

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You may want to add a \``pwd`\` to your command. You may find that you're indeed on a RO filesystem (e.g., "/"). At that stage you can either move to a RW filesystem, or remount the RO filesystem as RW.